# In C++, can two translation units be identical?

Tags: c++, gcc, standards, ld, one-definition-rule

The [circa-C++20 spec](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/lex.separate#def:translation_unit) says that a translation unit is

> A source file together with all the headers and source files included
> via the preprocessing directive #include, less any source lines
> skipped by any of the conditional inclusion preprocessing directives

It also says that:

> Translation units can be separately translated and then later linked to produce an executable program.

And [that a "program" is](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.link#def:program):

> one or more translation units linked together.

Elsewhere it gives the "[One Definition Rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr)", essentially stating that most things in the program need to only be defined once in the program.

So, I can make myself a translation unit. I can have `library.hpp`:

```
int do_thing();
```

And `library.cpp`:

```
#include "library.hpp"
int do_thing() {
    return 5;
}
```

And I can compile it:

```
$ g++ -c library.cpp -o library.o
```

Then I can have another translation unit with `executable.cpp`:

```
#include "library.hpp"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return do_thing();
}
```

And I can compile that:

```
$ g++ -c executable.cpp -o executable.o
```

And if I point the compiler at each translation unit once, I can make a program:

```
$ g++ -o executable executable.cpp library.cpp
```

But if I provide the root source file of the `library.cpp` translation unit twice, it doesn't work:

```
$ g++ -o executable executable.cpp library.cpp library.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBk6bKc.o: in function `do_thing()':
library.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `do_thing()'; /tmp/ccEigs7b.o:library.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand *why* this happens: the compiler just makes each `.cpp` I pass into a `.o`, and the linker just visits the `.o` files in the order supplied, and uses each one to fulfill undefined references to symbols from previous ones. If it encounters one that defines a symbol it already saw a definition for, it decides that that's an error.

But I don't see how this reconciles with the C++ spec: I've asked for a program to be compiled, and I've got one translation unit ("source file together with all the headers and source files included...") that defines this function, even if I have shown it to the compiler twice, so the program should be allowed.

**In the C++ specification, can multiple distinct "translation units" exist that are *the same* source file and *the same* final list of preprocessed lines?** Or else **does the definition as "one or more translation units" allow a "program" to potentially include multiple distinct instances of one translation unit** (at which point it is highly likely to be a program that breaks the one definition rule, as it would have multiple distinct instances of any definitions from the translation unit)?

If it were just a GCC limitation that I wasn't allowed to pass the same translation unit twice on the same command line, I would be OK with that, except I'm running into problems where the `.o` file from a translation unit ends up coming into a program both through a static library linked in at build time, and a dynamic library loaded at runtime, and *that* doesn't seem to work either, when I really would like it to. I am having trouble reading the spec as prohibiting it, as long as the translation unit really is the same, and the compiler flags are all the same, but `ld.so` doesn't seem able to consistently pull it off.

Comment: An empty file is a valid translation unit, and you can compile and link as many identical empty files as you wish.

Comment: A file containing only `inline` functions would work too.  `inline` symbols are not subject to the One Definition Rule.

Comment: Why do you think this goes against what the C++ standard says.  You are allowed **one** definition, you provided **two**, so you violate the **one** definition rule.

Comment: A file containing only `inline` functions would work too. `inline` symbols are subject to the One Definition Rule; each definition needs to be the same.  The `inline` keyword signifies *weak linkage*.

Comment: From the ODR link you posted: `10 Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement; no diagnostic required. The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined` - it does not depend on translation units/libraries etc.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm expecting the compiler to see that `library.cpp` and `library.cpp` are one and the same translation unit, because they are the same file on disk, at the same inode, with the same content and the same preprocessor result. And that translation unit defines each thing one time. What I'm actually getting is two distinct translation units with the same file and the same content, and I'm struggling to understand how that can be a thing *in the ontology defined by the C++ standard*, as opposed to just in the memory of the compiler.

Comment: You tell the compiler to compile two files, and it does. It doesn't care that they are the same.  It compiles them like you asked and then tries to link, which then gives you the error.  The C++ standard doesn't have anything to say about that, the correct commands to compile your program is not dictated by the standard.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I recall seeing somewhere that in pedantic mode empty translation units aren't actually allowed. But if they were, are all those empty files *the same* translation unit? Or can one empty file, at one place on disk, with one name, ever be *multiple distinct* translation units?

Comment: @interfect I don't know of any compiler that looks at the source files given to see if they are the same file. Consider a project thousands of source files which would need to be compared to each other. At best, you could use a hash set, but it still sounds like a needless build-time cost. I don't really see a significant benefit if the project is already correctly configured.

Comment: "I'm expecting the compiler to see that library.cpp and library.cpp are one and the same translation unit," - C++ doesn't care about files and a translation unit doesn't even have to *be* a file.